# Question about some algebra of conditional expectation

Tags: statistics, random-variables, proof-explanation, conditional-expectation, expected-value

$$
\begin{aligned}\mathbb{E}_{W|Z}\left[\mathbb{E}_{WY|W,Z}\left[WY\;|\;W,Z=z\right]\;|\;Z=z\right] = \mathbb{E}_{W|Z}\left[W\mathbb{E}_{Y|W, Z}\left[Y\;|\;W, Z=z\right]\;|\;Z=z\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

I'm wondering if this is a true statement where $W, Y, Z$ are random variables. But I'm not sure why exactly this is true (or false). My intuition is that $W$ becomes a constant but why does it become a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality is true even without the outer conditional expectation. Loosely speaking, since $W$ is being conditioned on in the conditional expectation $E[\cdot \mid W, Z=z]$, it is "known" and thus can be treated as a non-random quantity: $E[WY \mid W, Z=z] = W E[Y \mid Z=z]$ is just the same as $E[2Y] = 2 E[Y]$. [This can be made rigorous.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties).

Comment: I'm guessing you mean this: If $X$ is $H$-measurable, then $\mathbb{E}(XY\;|\;H) = X\mathbb{E}(Y\;|\;H)$, which I will have to look up. If you have any proof for this I would really appreciate it since I only see this on an "intuitive" level but not a mathematical level (for the general case). Thanks!

Comment: @Charles yes that's exactly the result, and it is one of the properties in the section of the Wikipedia page that I linked to. Proving this simply amounts to examining the rigorous definition of conditional expectation $E[XY \mid \mathcal{H}]$ and checking that $X E[Y \mid \mathcal{H}]$ satisfies the necessary properties.